# Dynamic widths for breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breadcrumbs

I'm kinda stuck here and I'm looking for some ideas. I have a breadcrumb system which uses `:before` and `:after` tags for the arrows.

[image]

The maximum width for all the breadcrumbs put together is `735px` as that is the size of the container element.

Now; I need to restrict the length of each breadcrumb to stop them overflowing and to ensure that they all stay on one line. To do this, I will need to set a maximum width on the breadcrumb. However the `max-width` will depend on the number of breadcrumbs which are currently visible.

I know that the easiest way would be to count the number of breadcrumbs present and set a fixed position by dividing the container width by the number of breadcrumbs, but this is ***not*** what I want - It would mean that breadcrumbs with a shorter title have a large gap, like below.
[image]

So I need to specify a `max-width`, but the `max-width` will depend on the width of the other breadcrumbs.

For example, if all the breadcrumbs have a fairly long title, the `max-width` will need to be small enough to allow all breadcrumbs to fit in the container.

But if, say, five of the breadcrumbs have very short titles (ie 4 characters) and the fifth one has a longer title, I would want the `max-width` to allow all the text on the last breadcrumb to be displayed, but still ensuring that the breadcrumbs still fit inside the container.

Sorry if this is too confusing. Here's a jsFiddle of my breadcrumbs so you can understand how they're structured. If you need any more information please let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/5CLYt/

The second example in the jsFiddle shows how the `max-width` needs to be dependant on the width of the other breadcrumbs, and not just the number of the breadcrumbs displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the answer of @JAYBEkster, you could consider using flexbox.
Here is a great resource: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've updated your fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/5CLYt/1/

```
/*

COPIED FROM: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

*/

#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I know this is not what you want, since the space between the items is growing and not the items it self. But maybe it' the right direction.

Maybe keep this question updated.

Update 2: flexbox is awesome.
It works with firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/5CLYt/3/

All you needed to do was:

```
.breadcrumbButton
{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add display:table for your container; add display:table-cell for each child and remove floating;

Comment: How does that fix the max-width problem?

Comment: This method could be used, however it removes the margin between each child. http://jsfiddle.net/5CLYt/2/ Any workaround for this?

Comment: This is pretty clever. You can add `border-spacing: 20px` to the container. Although the :after elements of not current elements disappear